# My Windows Phone 7 animations look clunky on the emulator - should I be worried?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm doing a phone app with some animations and they look really clunky on the emulator.  I don't have a phone yet so this is the only way I can test my app.

Sometimes the animations start late (up to a second after user input) and the they are almost always very jagged.  Far from the smooth fades and transitions that I've seen on the interwebs.   I'm not using anything hairy - just basic rotations and opacity fades on one or two elements.

Does anyone else see this in the emulator?  If not, i guess I have a bug somewhere.  If so, is there a work around?  Should I bump the priority of the xde.exe in process explorer?  Other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a consequence of gpu detection no working on your system.

You can verify this by checking if you can see the frame rate counters.

[Jeff Wilcox – Frame rate counters in Windows Phone](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/)

Note the emulator system requirements here also.

[Setup and System Requirements for Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626524%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I'm getting like 11-15 frames per second probably because I'm out of RAM.  Still not sure how to check if GPU detection is working...  Because my frame reates are so low, does that mean it's not working?  Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: If you can see the framerate counters, then you have gpu detection. They do not show without it.

Comment: yes, virtualisation support needs to be enabled in your bios too.. that catches people out occasionally

Comment: do you have the requisite 2GB RAM also?

Comment: run the VS as an admin and make a release ver of the app yet I belive that is the emulator.